# Is "Dabiq" an ISIS-produced magazine?

Tags: media, isis

The magazine *[Dabiq](http://www.clarionproject.org/news/islamic-state-isis-isil-propaganda-magazine-dabiq)* is [generally thought](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dabiq_(magazine)) to be a propaganda magazine produced by the proponents on [Islamic State of Iraq and the Levant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_State_of_Iraq_and_the_Levant) (a.k.a. ISIS, ISIL or IS).

> The Islamic State (ISIS) regularly puts out a glossy propaganda magazine aimed at recruiting jihadists from the West. It is sophisticated, slick, beautifully produced and printed in several languages including English.
>
> [...]
>
> 'Dabiq' as it is called, bills itself as "a periodical magazine focusing on the issues of tawhid (unity), manhaj (truth-seeking), hijrah (migration), jihad (holy war) and jama'ah (community). It will also contain photo reports, current events, and informative articles on matters relating to the Islamic State."

However, an answer on a [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6174/does-isis-justify-its-attacks-based-on-the-actions-of-others/6175#6175) question suggests:

> If you read their magazine "Dabiq", you even may come under first impression that it is anti-ISIS propaganda.

Is the magazine produced by ISIS? Or is it a hoax by ISIS's opponents to discredit ISIS along the lines of the Russian secret police producing *[The Protocols of the Elders of Zion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Protocols_of_the_Elders_of_Zion)*?

Comment: Any good reason to doubt it?

Comment: @Spork one [comment](http://politics.stackexchange.com/a/6175) said "If you read their magazine "Dabiq", you even may come under first impression that it is anti-ISIS propaganda.", and [this article](http://scoopempire.com/isiss-magazine-dabiq-shockingly-legit/) notes how western-style and professional the magazine is. The fact that it's in English, rather than Arabic, makes me mildly suspicious.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, why woulnd't it be ISIS propaganda aimed at English speakers?

Comment: @Benjol I'm hoping that fighters from western countries are still the minority, rather than the majority!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, well that would be precisely what they're trying to change...

Comment: It's not English rather than Arabic, Wikipedia seems to say that it has an Arabic and an English version.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm-Can you provide a notable source for claiming it is a 'hoax by ISIS's opponents to discredit ISIS' because the answer from the source you have provided from Politics.SE clearly mentions "you even may come under first impression that it is anti-ISIS propaganda." Doesn't this mean that the readers have to understand that Dabiq is ISIS propaganda? Also, the answer mentions that 'They usually justify their actions with religious arguments." which is again replicated in that Dabiq magazine! So what else will convince you that Dabiq is ISIS propaganda?

Comment: @pericles316 the notable claim I'm questioning is that Dabiq is by ISIS.